# Why a new permission group is getting created by default when a workflow is created in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I am trying to add item permissions through workflow and I used "Add Permission" action from the ribbon in designer and changed the permissions of the item. But all i find now is a new group with "site name followed with workflow users" for example "ABC workflow users" where ABC is site name. I googled and found its the behavior of "Add permission" that creates this group. But i haven't find any explanation on why so. Did any body faced this scenario. Can anyone explain on why this happens so and will this effect any of the permissions of the users. I am using SharePoint 2010 designer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Add permission" action creates a new SharePoint group, grants that group the permissions you specified to the list item on which the workflow is running, and adds the users and/or groups you specified in the workflow to that group's members.

Comment: For that functionality, you would want to use the "Replace Permissions" action instead. Or, you could continue to use "Add Permissions" as you are now, and additionally "Remove Permissions" to remove the Contribute permission for those users.